# Excluir valores repetidos de uma variável

Tags: php

Vou apenas dar um exemplo mais simples para não ter que postar o código todo, não sei se isso e possível fazer.

```
$exemplo = "exemplo exemplo"

echo $exemplo;
```

Ao exibir essa variável com echo ele retorna "exemplo exemplo" , teria algum comando ou alguma coisa q possa usar para ele retornar apenas "exemplo" sem repetir a palavra?

Obs: nao posso alterar o valor da variavel nem por ,  pois o modo que uso para capturar ela me retorna exatamente como esta acima.

Comment: Os valores repetidos são sempre separados por "espaço"? No caso essa variável é um string normal certo? Você poderia transformar essa variável em um array, e no array retirar os iguais.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode transformar em um array usando o `implode()` e depois utilizar o `array_unique()` para remover todas palavras duplicadas, e depois voltar a string normal utilizando `implode()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$exemplo = "exemplo exemplo exemplo exemplo";
$exemplo = implode(" ", array_unique(explode(" ", $exemplo)));
echo $exemplo; // Saida  = "exemplo"
```

Comment: so para ver se entendi, vo usa explode para transformar em um array depois usa array unique e depois volta a uma string usando implode

Comment: @MatheusRocha exatamente.

Comment: estou capturando a variavel utilizando um script( postei ele na publicação) e acho que isso esta influenciando , pois o codigo n esta funcionando no meu programa.

Comment: @MatheusRocha você vem com problema A e recebe resposta para problema A, quando você aceita a resposta não pode reeditar sua pergunta colocando outros problemas, além da pergunta ficar sem foco perde a qualidade.